# Centering and spacing two subscript lines under a double integral

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting

I got the following equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[frenchstyle]{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
\[
    V_n
    = V_{n-2} \iint\limits_{\mathclap{\begin{subarray}{l}
                                      0<\theta<2\pi\\
                                      0<r<1
                                  \end{subarray}}}
      (1 - r^2)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} r\D{\theta}\D{r}
\]
\end{document}
```

whose subscripts I aligned and spaced as follows:

[image]

```
\newlength\mywidth
\settowidth{\mywidth}{$\mathsurround = 0pt \scriptstyle\theta$}

\[
    V_n
    = V_{n-2} \iint\limits_{\mathclap{\begin{subarray}{l}
                                          0<\theta<2\pi\\
                                          0<\makebox[\mywidth][c]{$\mathsurround = 0pt \scriptstyle r$}<1
                                      \end{subarray}}\mspace{-20mu}}
      (1 - r^2)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} r\D{\theta}\D{r}
\]
```

As you can see, both variables are centered in the middle line between the two integral symbols, and in order to uniformly align the four `<`, I centered the `r` in a box whose width if that of `\theta`.

Is there a less pedestrian way of getting the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a general purpose macro `\widerof`, with three arguments:

1. (optional, default `c`) the alignment in the box;
2. the symbol to print;
3. the symbol to compare the width with.

In the example I changed `0` to `-1` just to show all types of alignment. I also used `\smashoperator` from `mathtools`.

```latex
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[frenchstyle]{kpfonts}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\widerof}[3][c]{\mathpalette\widerof@{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\widerof@}[2]{\widerof@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\widerof@@}[4]{%
  % #1=math style, #2=alignment, #3=symbol to print, #4=symbol to compare to
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1#4$}%
  \makebox[\ifdim\wd\z@>\wd\tw@ \wd\z@\else \wd\tw@\fi][#2]{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
V_n=
V_{n-2}
\smashoperator{\iint\limits_{
  \substack{
    \widerof[r]{0}{-1} < \widerof{\theta}{r} < \widerof[l]{2\pi}{1} \\
    \widerof[r]{-1}{0} < \widerof{r}{\theta} < \widerof[l]{1}{2\pi}
  }
}} (1 - r^2)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} r\D{\theta}\D{r}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here, I use a TABstack. If you want the lines with less vertical gap, that can easily be done, as an optional argument to `\tabularstackunder` (default 3pt gap).

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage[frenchstyle]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\TABstackMath
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\[
\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptstyle}
    V_n
    = V_{n-2} \iint\limits_{\mathclap{\tabularstackunder{rcl}{
                                      0<&\theta&<2\pi}{
                                      0<&r&<1}}}
     (1 - r^2)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} r\D{\theta}\D{r}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `alignedat` environment.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[frenchstyle]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
  V_n = V_{n-2} \iint\limits_{\scriptsize\mathclap{
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
      0 &< \theta & &< 2\pi \\[-.6em]
      0 &< \:r & &< 1
    \end{alignedat}
  }}
  (1 - r^2)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} r\D{\theta}\D{r}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]